# Shopify - "no variant ID was passed to us."

Tags: shopify

I'm trying to set up the Shopify variant drop-down in the cart form. From some reason, the information isn't passing through. I keep getting: "We were not able to add this item to your shopping cart because no variant ID was passed to us."

Any ideas?

```
        <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="width: 100%">

                    <h2>Order Your Painting</h2>
                    <div id="order-form">
                        <div class="steps left">
                          <h3>1. Choose your canvas size</h3>
                          <div class="selector-wrapper">
                            <select class="single-option-selector" id="product-select-option-0">
                            <option value="11“x14” Canvas">11“x14” Canvas</option>
                            <option value="12”x16” Canvas">12”x16” Canvas</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="steps right">
                            <h3>2. Select a color family</h3>
                          <div class="selector-wrapper">
                            <select class="single-option-selector" id="product-select-option-1">
                              <option value="Blue Tones">Blue Tones</option>
                              <option value="Sepia Tones">Sepia Tones</option>
                            </select>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="steps left">
                          <h3>3. Upload your photo</h3>
                          <div>Select a File to Upload</div>
                          <p><input type="file" id="photo" name="properties[Photo]" /></p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="steps right" id="payment">
                          <h3>4. Checkout with payment</h3>
                          <div id="cc">
                            <input type="hidden" name="return_to" value="/checkout" />
                            <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" value="Add to cart">
                          </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>


                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code:

```
<select class="single-option-selector" id="product-select-option-0">
   <option value="11“x14” Canvas">11“x14” Canvas</option>
   <option value="12”x16” Canvas">12”x16” Canvas</option>
</select>
```

Do you have a valid variant ID in there? Seems not. Shopify has no idea what a value="11“x14” Canvas" is. Instead of rendering that, try using the variant id. Your form will submit, Shopify will know what to put in the cart, and that error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

What Dave said. See this doc please: http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/5-themes/can-i-make-my-theme-use-products-with-multiple-options